# Pose mode scaling

Tags: transforms, pose-mode

The same question was 8 years ago, no answer yet.

When I scale a bone in pose mode it will also affect the size of a bone connected to it. How can do it so that the connected bone keeps the same size?

And/or how to get scale value for far child bone? Only check all parents and multiplication scale?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

In *Edit* or *Pose* mode, go into the *Bone panel > Relations > Inherit Scale > None*.

If you want to choose *None* for several bones at once, select them, press <kbd>Alt</kbd> while you click on the dropdown menu, then choose *None*, it will assign *None* to all these bones.

[image]

Comment: thanks, as far as I understand, it need to do  for each child bones

Comment: You can select all the bones and press Alt when you click on the dropdown menu, then choose None, it will assign None to all the selected bones  @Salexrock